# A question about the inequality $ax > |x-a|$ where $0 < a < 1$

Tags: inequality

The question is

> Solve the inequality $ax > |x-a|$ where $0 < a < 1$

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: split it into two cases, one for $x\ge a$ and one for $x<a$?

Comment: Yes but I couldnt manage to find the correct answer :(

Comment: If you add your work, we can indicate where you went wrong.

Comment: Since |x-a|< ax, I tried -ax < x-a < ax but nothing comes out of it. I feel like I couldn't implement 0 < a < 1

Answer (score 1):

Examine two cases:

- $x - a \geq 0 \implies x \geq a$
- $x-a \lt 0\implies x\lt a$

Recall that $$|t| = \begin{cases} -t& t\lt 0\\ t & t\geq 0\end{cases}$$

In this case, $|t| = |x-a|$.

If $x\lt a$, then we have the inequality $$a x > -(x - a)$$

If $x \geq a $, we have the inequality $$ax > (x - a)$$

Comment: This comes down to "-ax < x-a < ax" however I can't move forward from there. What am I missing?

Comment: Work each case separately

Comment: You're welcome, Mehmet!

Answer (score 1):

Since for $x<0$ the inequality $|x-a|<ax$ is clearly false, your inequality is equivalent to
$$
-ax<x-a<ax,\qquad x\ge0
$$
that is, to the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x-a>-ax\\
x-a<ax\\
x\ge0
\end{cases}
$$
The first inequality can be rewritten $x(1+a)>a$, the second one as $x(1-a)<a$, so
we get
$$
\frac{a}{1+a}<x<\frac{a}{1-a}
$$

Try to find out where the hypothesis $0<a<1$ has been used.